# 1 day folder on my webserver lost permissions

Tags: permissions, chown

I've ubuntu server 12.04. I try to upload image on one of my wp installations on this box, and I get permission error (worked perfectly few days back). I log in and check permissions and I see ownership 1632 1673.

I quickly fixed it by running `chown -R www-data:www-data .`

But I don't understand how this could happen in the first place.
Should I be worried about security? or this can happen on unix from time to time?

Comment: Is this a dedicated server? Are you the sys admin?

Comment: @don.joey  this is VPS. And yes I'm the admin